# Finding Request URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging, url, bookmarklet, http-request

I am creating a bookmarklet which opens up url in a proxy when for pages which are not loading  (an example could be ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT in chrome).

However, I am not able to fetch urls of such pages. For others (blocked by ISP) url is fetching correctly.

I am using `location.href` to get url.

Comment: Have you tried using document.URL instead of location.href?

Comment: @Terric yes I tried, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.location.host` to get the URL:

```
 if (/blocked/i.test(document.body.innerHTML) )
   {
   location.href = /* Proxy URL */ 
   }
```